# bitwise conversion of decimal numbers to binary

Tags: c++, binary, decimal

The code works fine for some values like for eg 10 the output is 1010 which is correct but for 20 or 50 or 51 the output is wrong or atleast seems so to me.
please help !

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <math.h>
    using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int n;

    cin >> n;

    int ans = 0;

    int i = 0;

    while (n != 0)
    {

        int bit = n & 1;

        ans = (bit * pow(10, i)) + ans;

        n = n >> 1;

        i++;
    }

    cout << " Answer is " << ans << endl;
}
```

Comment: _"for 20 or 50 or 51 the output is wrong or atleast seems so to me"_ So what **is** the output in those cases?

Comment: Just remember all your numbers are already stored in binary in memory (so the bit pattern is there).  So combining bit (2^n) with (10^n) is a bit strange. on top of that pow is floating point function. So I think you need to rethink your code a bit. You might want to have a look here : https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/bitwise-operators/

Comment: I really dont know if this is some problem with my compiler only but i tried changing the data type of the ans variable from (int to float) and it worked perfectly fine really don't know the reason here as far as the asnwers go for those cases when ans was int data type for my compiler binary values for 6 , 20 , 51 were 109, 10098 , 11010 respectively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying to run your code, it works. 51 correctly comes out as 110011 and 50 as 110010 and 20 as 10100. Those are the correct bit values, you can try calculating them by counting or by just adding 10 (i.e. 1010) in different ways.

Comment: thank you so much my guy the code is fien i guess my compiler was having some isues i changed the datatype of ans variable from int to float and the code worked perfectly fine previously the answers for 6, 20, 51 were 109 , 10098 , 11010 respectively

Answer (score 1):

change datatype of ans.

```
float ans = 0;
```

Comment: No, this is how you get incorrect answers. `pow` shouldn't be used at all. Avoid floating point math when there's only integers involved.